# Config php ini file for upload files

Tags: php, file-upload, php-ini

I have a page for upload files, In `.htaccess` file I have this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 40M
```

I have an img, with size 1.6 MB. When I am trying to upload this image, I obtain the error below.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 54525952 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3600 bytes) in....

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: There's also `memory_limit` in php.ini that can affect upload. And don't forget restarting server. I don't think that uploading 1.6 MB image will take too long but if it will you can change `max_execution_time ` and `max_input_time` too.

Comment: Please post your code. You appear to be loading the complete file into memory, which is probably avoidable.

Comment: I use php GD library for change images size, max width must be 900 px, and uploading img have width 4000px, may be problem was from this?  when I add in htaccess file: **php_value memory_limit 56M** problem resolved. post my code here no sense, bacause its very big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you can cant access **php.ini** on server then write below in your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

Answer (score 3):

```
You need to set following values to increase file upload size

    file_uploadsile_uploads
    upload_max_filesize
    max_input_time
    memory_limit
    max_execution_time
    post_max_size

Cheers
```

Answer (score 1):

You have memory_limit in your PHP configuration; 54525952 bytes which is 52MB.

You should configure memory_limit in php.ini or .htaccess or fix memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you're probably exhausting the memory_limit of PHP, that is, PHP is trying to allocate an amount of memory greater that the memory_limit param value.

Maybe you're uncompressing the image on the fly or copying some data that needs too much memory to be allocated, try increasing that limit.