# Upload video or picture with php

Tags: php, html, image, video, upload

I am trying to upload video or pictures to my server using php. However I keep getting an error it seems like the file name is empty and I don't understand why, the code keeps executing the script showing an error and nothing is uploaded to my folder

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container" id="step2-video" style="display:none; margin-top:100px" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <form id="video_uploader" action="ad_creator.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div id="btn-upload-video">
                                <span class="file-wrapper btn ad-choice">
                                    <input type="file" id="video-file-upload" name="video-file-upload" accept="video/mp4"/> 
                                    <span class="button">Choose a video</span>                              
                                </span>
                            </div>                              
                            <div id="video-preview" style="display:none" >      
                                <span class="file-wrapper btn ad-choice">   
                                    <?php

                                    ?>                      
                                    <input type="submit" name="upload_video" value="Submit" style="margin-left:auto" />
                                    <span class="button">Comfirm</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>                 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <!-- 
            Step 2 for pictures of the editor
            -->

            <div class="container" id="step2-picture" style="display:none; margin-top:100px" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <form id="picture_uploader" action="ad_creator.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div id="btn-upload-picture">
                                <span class="file-wrapper btn ad-choice">
                                    <input type="file" id="picture-file-upload" name="picture-file-upload" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png"/> 
                                    <span class="button">Choose a picture</span>                                
                                </span>
                            </div>                              
                            <div id="picture-preview" style="display:none" >
                                <div id="imagePreview"></div>
                                <br>        
                                <span class="file-wrapper btn ad-choice">                           
                                    <input type="submit" name="upload_picture" value="Submit" style="margin-left:auto" />
                                    <span class="button">Comfirm</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['upload_picture'])){

                    $image_name = isset ($_FILES['image']['name']) ? $_FILES['image']['name'] : '' ;
                    $image_type = isset($_FILES['image']['type']) ? $_FILES['image']['type'] : '';
                    $image_size = isset($_FILES['image']['size']) ? $_FILES['image']['size'] : '';
                    $image_tmp_name = isset ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] : '';

                    if($image_name == ''){
                        echo "<script> alert ('Error occured for picture upload')</script>";
                        exit();             
                    } else {
                        move_uploaded_file ($image_tmp_name, "uploads/picture/$image_name");
                        echo "<script> alert ('sucess for puciture upload')</script>";
                    }
                }   

                if (isset($_POST['upload_video'])){

                    $video_name = isset ($_FILES['video']['name']) ? $_FILES['video']['name'] : '' ;
                    $video_type = isset($_FILES['video']['type']) ? $_FILES['video']['type'] : '';
                    $video_size = isset($_FILES['video']['size']) ? $_FILES['video']['size'] : '';
                    $video_tmp_name = isset ($_FILES['video']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'] : '';

                    if($video_name == ''){
                        echo "<script> alert ('Error occured for video upload')</script>";
                        exit();             
                    } else {
                        move_uploaded_file ($video_tmp_name, "uploads/video/$video_name");
                        echo "<script> alert ('Sucess for video upload')</script>";
                    }
                }   

            ?>
```

***SOLUTION***

From Rescaltt, thank you. 
I was checking for the wrong file input, 
I was checking for `$_FILES['image']['name']` instead of `$_FILES['picture-file-upload']['name']`

Comment: What error are you getting? It's hard to diagnose with such little information.

Comment: You name your file input `name="picture-file-upload"` but you are checking for `$_FILES['image']`. Likely that will be a problem. Same with the video name(s).

Comment: Also you are using redundant code (ie. you are duplicating code for no good reason). Turn your upload code into a function and use a variable(s) to check elements in your `$_POST` and/or `$_FILES`.

Comment: @Rasclatt i dont actually get an error, the code just always execut echo "<script> alert ('Error occured for video upload')</script>"; therefore and does not upload anything

Comment: Ok then see my comments. I think you are not checking the right names

Comment: Likely should be checking `$_FILES['picture-file-upload']['name']` etc.

Comment: this works however my picture of video is still not uploaded for some reason

Comment: What? I am not sure what that means "my picture of video is still not uploaded." What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the code now gets into } else {
                        move_uploaded_file ($video_tmp_name, "uploads/video/$video_name");
                        echo "<script> alert ('Sucess for video upload')</script>";
                    } and display the alert however, the picture is not uploaded to my folder

Comment: You mean the video is not uploaded?

Comment: neither video or picture, i tired both and neither are uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a function to do both. Things to note, you should probably do a couple checks and balances:

1. Sanitize the file name for good measure.
2. Include your document root for an absolute path or make sure you have the proper relative path.
3. You may want to check that the upload folder exists and make it if not.
4. Check success on upload `if(move_uploaded_file(...etc.`

---

```
<?php 
function MyUploader($uploadtype = 'picture',$savedir = '/uploads/')
    {
        $name       =   (isset($_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['name']))? $_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['name'] : '' ;
        $type       =   (isset($_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['type']))? $_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['type'] : '';
        $size       =   (isset($_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['size']))? $_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['size'] : '';
        $tmp_name   =   (isset($_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['tmp_name']))? $_FILES[$uploadtype.'-file-upload']['tmp_name'] : '';

        if(empty($name)) 
            return "<script> alert ('Invalid file name.')</script>";             
        else {
            // Make sure you include your ROOT DIRECTORY / correct local path
            $upload_dir =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$savedir.$uploadtype."/";
            // May want to make the directory if not exists
            if(!is_dir($upload_dir))
                mkdir($upload_dir,0755,true);
            // You should check that it worked with if(move_upload_file(...etc                  
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir.$name))
                return "<script> alert ('$uploadtype uploaded successfully')</script>";
            else
                return "<script> alert ('Could not save file to server.')</script>";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['upload_picture']))
        echo MyUploader('picture');

    if(isset($_POST['upload_video']))
        echo MyUploader('video'); ?>
```

Comment: The code still goes to else
                     return "<script> alert ('Could not save file to server.')</script>";  I have checked if the path of the folder is correct and it is. I really don't understand where the error could be.

Comment: Let me check it on my server and see if I get same error.

Comment: The code works. I just checked it. You should `print_r($_FILES);` and see if you get an error in there or you may have a permissions error or perhaps your `php_ini` file is not configured properly. There are a couple of settings in this file that will limit file size allowed to upload, etc.

Comment: its all done in local host, here is what print_r comes out with Array ( [video-upload] => Array ( [name] => SAM_1457.MP4 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: Yup, `error` should be `0` not `1` and you should have a `tmp_name` and `size` should not be `0`. Look into your `php_ini` file settings.

Comment: Did you try a photo? A photo is smaller and may work.

Comment: just did and again hereis what print_r come out with Array ( [picture-upload] => Array ( [name] => SAM_1422.JPG [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: Your PHP settings are likely not allowing you to upload. That array would be populated like: `Array ( [picture-upload] => Array ( [name] => SAM_1422.JPG [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /datatmp/php5Jmvza [error] => 0 [size] => 32867 ) )` if the PHP upload was working. So the code is not the problem, it's your server settings

Comment: is there any particulare config to make in php.ini ?! I have not modified it, what could be wrong with it ?

Comment: Check out this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260453/config-php-ini-file-for-upload-files or this one http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/ or this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: I am using Xampp so i guess I can edit my php.ini, however it still does not work, all these post talk about the size of the file.

Comment: You may want to search for Xampp issues with file uploads. The above code works, so that part is solved. Your issue is with your server....unfortunately I don't know anything about running Xampp.  :\

Comment: ok thank you for your help i guess i'll keep searching i have been stuck with this for over a week ....

Comment: Well, you are almost there! Once you get that issue resolved your uploads will work, guaranteed!

Comment: I managed to make it work on a web server so like you said it does work, something is wrong with my localhost, However videos don't upload. I can upload picutres no probs but videos don't seem to work, you can try it at this adress http://g52grp.host22.com/ad_creator.php

Comment: Well since you are using the same code for both and you know it works on one, then it's going to be the server settings. Did you change max_upload in the `php_ini` settings?

Comment: i did, the problem is that no error message is displayed, no alert either. Normally the code would display an error alert if the file is not uploaded and would display a success alert if it is, but for video nothing is being displayed.